# Missing free space from ZFS pool after migrating from FreeBSD to NAS4Free

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I was running FreeBSD `10.0-RELEASE-p4` and migrated to NAS4Free which is FreeBSD version `10.2-RELEASE #0 r286738M: Thu Aug 13 21:32:58 CEST 2015`. Now I'm missing free space and I can't delete any files from the pool. Reading files works fine.

All drives are 2 TB. I didn't remember to export the pool before I migrated. According to internet sources exporting and importing pool should free the space but it doesn't. Pool is running version 15. Could upgrade or scrub help?

```
NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
storage     ONLINE       0     0     0
  raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    da0     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da3     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da6     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da9     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da12    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da15    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
  raidz2-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
    da1     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da4     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da7     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da10    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da13    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da16    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
  raidz2-2  ONLINE       0     0     0
    da2     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da5     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da8     ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da11    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da14    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
    da17    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
```

So: [((6 drives - 2 drives for parity) x 2 TB) x 3 raidz2 = 24 TB which is 21.83 tebibytes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%286-2%29%20*%202%20TB%29%20*%203%20in%20TiB) usable space minus metadata.

Properties:

```
# zpool get all
NAME     PROPERTY                       VALUE                          SOURCE
storage  size                           32.6T                          -
storage  capacity                       97%                            -
storage  altroot                        -                              default
storage  health                         ONLINE                         -
storage  guid                           14393350251601347202           local
storage  version                        15                             local
storage  bootfs                         -                              default
storage  delegation                     on                             default
storage  autoreplace                    off                            default
storage  cachefile                      -                              default
storage  failmode                       wait                           default
storage  listsnapshots                  off                            default
storage  autoexpand                     off                            default
storage  dedupditto                     0                              default
storage  dedupratio                     1.00x                          -
storage  free                           696G                           -
storage  allocated                      31.9T                          -
storage  readonly                       off                            -
storage  comment                        -                              default
storage  expandsize                     -                              -
storage  freeing                        0                              local
storage  fragmentation                  -                              -
storage  leaked                         0                              local
storage  feature@async_destroy          disabled                       local
storage  feature@empty_bpobj            disabled                       local
storage  feature@lz4_compress           disabled                       local
storage  feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump  disabled                       local
storage  feature@spacemap_histogram     disabled                       local
storage  feature@enabled_txg            disabled                       local
storage  feature@hole_birth             disabled                       local
storage  feature@extensible_dataset     disabled                       local
storage  feature@embedded_data          disabled                       local
storage  feature@bookmarks              disabled                       local
storage  feature@filesystem_limits      disabled                       local
storage  feature@large_blocks           disabled                       local
```

`zpool iostat` shows free space:

```
# zpool iostat -v
               capacity     operations    bandwidth
pool        alloc   free   read  write   read  write
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
storage     31.9T   696G      0      0    550    540
  raidz2    10.8T  63.1G      0      0    162      2
    da0         -      -      0      0    185    135
    da3         -      -      0      0    157    135
    da6         -      -      0      0    158    135
    da9         -      -      0      0    163    135
    da12        -      -      0      0    158    135
    da15        -      -      0      0    149    135
  raidz2    10.8T  90.1G      0      0    162      2
    da1         -      -      0      0    125    101
    da4         -      -      0      0    102    101
    da7         -      -      0      0    115    101
    da10        -      -      0      0    125    101
    da13        -      -      0      0    100    101
    da16        -      -      0      0    106    101
  raidz2    10.3T   543G      0      0    225    536
    da2         -      -      0      0    139    243
    da5         -      -      0      0    133    244
    da8         -      -      0      0    118    246
    da11        -      -      0      0    123    246
    da14        -      -      0      0    123    244
    da17        -      -      0      0    124    243
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
```

`zpool list` shows free space:

```
# zpool list storage
NAME      SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
storage  32.6T  31.9T   696G         -      -    97%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

`zfs list` doesn't show free space:

```
# zfs list
NAME      USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
storage  21.3T      0  21.3T  /mnt/storage
```

`df` doesn't show free space:

```
# df -ha
Filesystem      Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/xmd0       120M     69M     51M    58%    /
devfs           1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/xmd1       719M    260M    459M    36%    /usr/local
procfs          4.0K    4.0K      0B   100%    /proc
storage          21T     21T      0B   100%    /mnt/storage
/dev/xmd2       248M    3.9M    224M     2%    /var
tmpfs           128M     48K    128M     0%    /var/tmp
/dev/ada0s1a    743M    151M    592M    20%    /cf
```

There's no snapshots

```
# zfs list -t snapshot
no datasets available
```

Datasets:

```
# zdb -d storage
Dataset mos [META], ID 0, cr_txg 4, 50.0M, 565 objects
Dataset storage [ZPL], ID 16, cr_txg 1, 21.3T, 1111968 objects
Verified large_blocks feature refcount is correct (0)
```

Deduplication:

```
# zdb -D storage
All DDTs are empty
```

camcontrol:

```
# camcontrol devlist -v
scbus0 on mpt0 bus 0:
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (pass0,da0)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 1 lun 0 (pass1,da1)
<ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 CC43>        at scbus0 target 2 lun 0 (pass2,da2)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 3 lun 0 (pass3,da3)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 4 lun 0 (pass4,da4)
<ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 CC43>        at scbus0 target 5 lun 0 (pass5,da5)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 6 lun 0 (pass6,da6)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 7 lun 0 (pass7,da7)
<ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 CC43>        at scbus0 target 8 lun 0 (pass8,da8)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 9 lun 0 (pass9,da9)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 10 lun 0 (pass10,da10)
<ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 CC43>        at scbus0 target 11 lun 0 (pass11,da11)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 12 lun 0 (pass12,da12)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 13 lun 0 (pass13,da13)
<ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 CC43>        at scbus0 target 14 lun 0 (pass14,da14)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 15 lun 0 (pass15,da15)
<ATA SAMSUNG HD204UI 0001>         at scbus0 target 16 lun 0 (pass16,da16)
<ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 CC43>        at scbus0 target 17 lun 0 (pass17,da17)
<HP HP SAS EXP Card 2.06>          at scbus0 target 18 lun 0 (pass18,ses0)
<>                                 at scbus0 target -1 lun ffffffff ()
scbus1 on ata2 bus 0:
<>                                 at scbus1 target -1 lun ffffffff ()
scbus2 on ata3 bus 0:
<>                                 at scbus2 target -1 lun ffffffff ()
scbus3 on ata4 bus 0:
<KINGSTON SV300S37A60G 525ABBF0>   at scbus3 target 0 lun 0 (ada0,pass19)
<>                                 at scbus3 target -1 lun ffffffff ()
scbus4 on ata5 bus 0:
<>                                 at scbus4 target -1 lun ffffffff ()
scbus-1 on xpt0 bus 0:
<>                                 at scbus-1 target -1 lun ffffffff (xpt0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeBSD 10.2 added tunable, `vfs.zfs.spa_slop_shift`, which controls how much space is reserved by default.

Source: https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.2R/relnotes.html#storage-zfs